# "ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more detail" Showing in Firefox but not in Chrome. But Streaming is not working both browser from remote IP

Tags: webrtc, pubnub

"ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more detail"  Showing in Firefox but not in Chrome. But Streaming is not working both browser from remote IP.

I'm using pubnub WEBRTC. Its working fine in local connection. But its not working on Remote IP and showing "ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more detail" .

I also tried with VPN. But no results.

I need expert suggestion.

**FYI: (I can't use TURN server)**

Answer (score 2):

Some connections (~30%) won't work if you don't use a TURN server. If you can not use one then you need to accept that things are not going to work 30% of the time.

See [this html5rocks tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) for background information.

Comment: I tried it from USA, Bangladesh, Netherlands IP. All time failure. But its only work with Local LAN. So, if i setup windows default VPN service, would it be workable ?

Comment: It's not a matter of VPN, you have to use a TURN server : create you own one or do some tests with a free - but limited - account at xirsys.net